# LTCG doesn't remember that /O2 was specified at compile time

Tags: visual-c++, optimization, c++-cli

**Background**

I am using `CL` and `LINK` from the command line to build a project composed of native C++, mixed C++/CLI, and safe C++/CLI. I need to target .NET Framework 2.0-3.5 so I am using the VC90 toolchain (I have VS2010 but installed VS2008 C++ express and the SDK for Windows 7 and .NET 3.5 SP1 to get the complete VC90 toolchain).

If I try my script with the VS100 toolchain it works fine but targets .NET v4.0. If I don't use `/GL` for my native and mixed code it works. I know of these solutions, so don't suggest them. I am trying to understand why this is occurring.

**Problem**

If I use `/GL` and `/LTCG` I get many of the following warnings in the native code:

> xxx.cpp(###) : warning C4748: `/GS` can not protect parameters and local variables from local buffer overrun because optimizations are disabled in function

And the following error in the mixed code:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\vcclr.h(47) : error C4801: Return by reference is not verifiable: definition of returned local not found in basic block

The second one is for PtrToStringChars from a Microsoft header file that allows you to use a `String^` as `const wchar_t*` and is a function that MUST be inlined (and is marked inline). The "return by reference" won't actually be a return when inlined, thus no error.

The issue is that I do use optimizations while compiling! I use the standard `/O2` which has the highest level of inlining (`/Ob2`) and normally allows `/GS`.

**Script**

Here is my abridged compilation script

```
set TARGET=x86
call "%VS90COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" %TARGET%

set CL=/nologo /Zl /Zi /W4 /O2 /Oy- /GL /GS /EHa /MP /D NDEBUG /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /D INTEGRATED /Fdout\ /Foout\
set LINK=/nologo /LTCG /CLRIMAGETYPE:IJW /MACHINE:%TARGET% /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,6.0 /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /DEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib /DEFAULTLIB:msvcmrt.lib
set CSC=/nologo /w:4 /d:INTEGRATED /o+ /target:module

set CL_NATIVE=/c /FI"stdafx-native.h"
set CL_MIXED=/c /clr /LN /FI"stdafx-mixed.h"
set CL_PURE=/c /clr:safe /LN /GL /FI"stdafx-pure.h"

set NATIVE=a.cpp b.cpp ...
set MIXED=c.cpp d.cpp ...
set PURE=e.cpp f.cpp ...

cl %CL_NATIVE% %NATIVE%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

cl %CL_MIXED% %MIXED%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

cl %CL_PURE% %PURE%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

link /LTCG /NOASSEMBLY /DLL /OUT:"out\x.netmodule" out\*.obj
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Answer (score 2):

Short Version: **Inlining in MSIL takes place during JIT, after the code verifier performs accessibility checking.**

Long Version:

Whole-Program Optimization doesn't apply to MSIL, because MSIL always gets optimized across compile units, and even across assemblies (unless optimizations are turned off by debug).  I think this is the source of your warnings.

Many optimizations are the responsibility of the JIT, including inlining.  Coupled with accessibility checks, this prevents the C++ compiler from running an inlining pass on MSIL.  (What happens if a member function using private members get inlined in native C++?  Not much.  What happens if a member function using private members gets inlined in MSIL into a function that has no access to those private members?  The .NET runtime throws an absolute fit.  Everything you think you know about compiler settings for inlining just doesn't apply to MSIL.)  This is why...

...use of `PtrToStringChars` is incompatible with `/clr:safe` because it isn't verifiable.  It should be fine with `/clr` though, and also with `/clr:pure` since neither of those try to create verifiable assemblies.  As mentioned, the compiler is not allowed to inline when compiling in `/clr` modes.  This is the source of your error.

A final problem is creation of a netmodule.  I'm pretty sure that mixed-mode code has to be created as full-blown assemblies and not netmodules.

Comment: `PtrToStringChars` is used by the code that is 'mixed' as interop between the `/clr:safe` and native code. It is only included in the `stdafx-mixed.h` header. So that is compiled with `/clr`. I tell the linker to use `/clr` (`/CLRIMAGETYPE:IJW`).

Comment: On the `netmodule` thing. It is supposed to be possible (and I have gotten it to partially work). See [Linking native C++ into C# applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/texblog/archive/2007/04/05/linking-native-c-into-c-applications.aspx) which is my eventual goal.

Comment: @thiamin: Go study that blog article a lot more closely.  Native code never ends up in a netmodule.  Rather, the C# netmodule is pulled in by the C++ linker to create a single mixed-mode PE.  But you're not even getting to the link like yet, since compilation fails.  Try moving /GL and /GS to the native compile options, they don't have any benefits when compiling managed code.

Comment: @thaimin: Sorry, misspelled your handle in the last comment.  Commenting again to make sure you get notified.

Comment: @BenVoigt Pure and some mixed managed code do get put into the initial netmodule. The C# is compiled with that netmodule to create a new netmodule. Then all the objs and C# netmodule are linked together into an EXE. During either linking step using `LTCG` causes those warnings/errors only for native and mixed code compiled with `GL` and `GS`. Even if I delay the `LTCG` until the final link it still doesn't work. If I don't have `GL` for either native or mixed code, I can compile an EXE (and as you stated `GL` for pure code does nothing so no problems).

Comment: @thaimin: There's never any mixed or native code in a netmodule, I don't think they have any native symbol table at all.  I guess the managed portion of a mixed project could be, and according to that blog article, you need `/LN` for that, which you don't seem to be using.  Wait, yes you are using `/LN`.  Then why are you trying to build a netmodule in your final link?  You should be pulling in the C# netmodule there, not trying to create a C++ netmodule.

Comment: @BenVoigt For your reference, you are answering my other question as well which has the rest of the script. In short I must create a netmodule out of the C++ since the C# code references the C++ code and it can't include the headers. The alternative way to do that step is to do `/addmodule:a.obj` for each object file that declares a class needed in the C# code (or to compile one file that includes all the appropriate headers). Regardless, the final link while creating an EXE experiences the same issue (when using one of these workarounds).